# Aborting an outer function from within a function that it calls

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Is it possible to make `youth` return/stop executing from within `box`? Directly, not something like:

```
function youth(){
  var check = true;

  function box(){
    //code
    check = false;
  }

  //code
  while(check){
    //code;
  }
  return false;    
}
```

(where there is a `check` variable which `box` changes)

Comment: could you precise what are you trying to achieve? and quote real code?

Comment: @difitalFresh I modified the title of your post in an attempt to better summarize your question. If I erred and did not summarize correctly, please modify it and whack me on the knuckles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot, unless you throw an exception from the inner function (but that doesn't really count as "returning," and it's not really a good design pattern anyway).

It does not make sense to allow a function to make its caller return a value, since the calling function might not even be declared in the same context -- perhaps it is some other function that accepts a function argument, and that passed-in function shouldn't be able to modify the called function's behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some important idea to make my code look like that.

Comment: @digitalFresh: The return value of the function can always be used to accomplish this.  For example, the inner function could return true if it wants to continue executing; then you would just have to write `if (!box()) { return; }`.